# SObject.OwnerID returns Null

Tags: apex

When trying to access the OwnerID of a record via Apex, It returns null. I tried multiple objects (Standard and Custom) as well as before and after trigger contexts.

Examples:

```
Opportunity.OwnerID //Returns Null

CustomObject__c.OwnerID //Returns Null
```

Comment: Could you post some more of your code?

Comment: Why this is happening is going to depending on where you got the object from, i.e. a query or a trigger context variable.  If from a trigger context variable specify the event, i.e. after insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only actual instances of objects have their fields set.

The code you have written tries to find an Id on an object definition, not on an actual object. You might have been confused with a similar SOQL query structure:

```
[Select Opportunity.OwnerId from Opportunity where ...]
```

However, this queries the `Opportunity` object and returns a list of Opportunity instances. See similar question [How to get the ID of Custom Object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12401/how-to-get-the-id-of-custom-object/12403#12403).