# Getting object name using object ID

Tags: salesforce-id

My requirement is how to get the object name using Object ID. First 3 places of the record Id depends on Object name. Is there any method to getting the Object name to pass the record Id...?? If anyone knows update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use Following method to get the SObjectType

```
Id someId = '00590000000eF8z';
System.debug(someId.getSObjectType());
```

Output :

User

Answer (score 0):

GET OBJECT NAME FROM RECORD ID?
String sObjName = myRecordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();